# Is there any way to restore the previous DOORS session

Tags: ibm-doors

Assume I made mistakes in present DOORS session and saved them. I cannot change them back after saving. There is no 'Undo'.

Is there any way to restore the previous DOORS session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way of restoring a specific session of DOORS, at least not using DOORS built-in functions. To do this, you will have to either roll back the changes manually or script something to automate the process via DXL. Though this assumes you have your module setup to generate all necessary history records you need for the roll back process.

Either manual or automatic would follow some sort of process that looks like this:

1. Open the baseline immediately after the session you want. If the session is after the latest baseline, open the Current version of the module. This reduces the total number of potential changes you need to sift through to determine whether they are relevant.
2. Look through module history and identify all history records made after a certain session based on the timestamp or session number. Discarding any history records that modify the similar information. For example, creating a link and then deleting that same link, or editing the name of an attribute. You would want to discard the newer history records because only the oldest record will contain the value you're interested in for your session.
3. Look through object history and identify all history records made after a certain session based on the timestamp or session number. Discarding any history records that are modifying the same attribute at a later date. In other words, only keep the oldest history records for analysis.
4. Rollback changes to the old value found on the history records identified in steps 2 and 3.

If you want to go the automated route by scripting something in DXL, you can look up the relevant methods with regards to processing History Records in the History sub-section (under the Module main section) of the DXL User Manual.

Of course this also assumes you haven't hard deleted anything from your module that needs to be rolled back, at which point the DOORS history entry will display "Read Locked Data". By hard delete I mean things like deleting attributes or purging objects. These operations will leave history records that effectively have no history information that can be accessed.